# Why is this lemma true?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, geometry, analysis

In Lemma 2 of [this paper](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s1-26/3/198.full.pdf+html), which states that, given $l$ lines in the plane, and given $\delta > 0$, there are at least
$l/( [\delta^{-1}] +1)$ of the lines, such that the angle between any two of them is less than $\delta\pi$, 
if one takes $\delta=1/4$ and $l=15$,
then there would be $3$ of the lines, such that the angle between
any two of the 3 lines is less than $\pi/4$.

But for any three lines in the plane, since the sum of the three angles is $\pi$, we
know that there are at least two lines the angle between which is
at least $\pi/3$.

So why is the lemma true?

Comment: Thanks for any helpful answers!

Comment: As far as I can see, your link leads nowhere: either it doesn't exist or else that site is down.

Comment: Please make the question self-contained, or at the very least fix the link.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Thank you for pointing it out. The right link has been added now.

Comment: @Joanie , do you really expect people to pay for reading that paper? Not all are in their universitites to access it for free. You better write down the exact problem or else lots of people, I'm afraid, won't even know what it is about.

Comment: @DonAntonio, I have now added the statement of the lemma. Thanks.

Comment: Consider three lines at angles $1^\circ$, $2^\circ$, and $3^\circ$ to the horizontal. Do you think that the angle between two of them is at least $\pi/3$?

Comment: I think the authors mean that when you take the angle between two lines, you should always take the angle between 0 and 90 degrees (i.e. the smaller of the two possible angles).  When you consider the angles between the three lines, the smaller angles will not necessarily be the interior angles of a triangle.

Comment: @HughThomas: Thank you for the comment. But how to show the lemma for δ=1/4 and l=15?

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that all lines go through the same point (this is really irrelevant assumption, but makes it easier to imagine things). Let's the split half-circle (angle $\pi$) into parts of size $\delta\pi$. We get

$$n = \left\lceil \frac{\pi}{\delta\pi} \right\rceil = \left\lceil \delta^{-1} \right\rceil$$

areas. Note that each two lines within a single slice have an angle at most $\delta\pi$ between them.

So, we have $l$ objects (lines) and $n$ containers (areas) in which to put them. Using the [Pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), we see that there must exist an area with at least

$$L = \left\lceil \frac{l}{n} \right\rceil$$

lines in it, so there are at least $L$ lines with the angle at most $\delta\pi$ between each two of them. Using what we know about $n$, we get:

$$L = \left\lceil \frac{l}{n} \right\rceil = \left\lceil \frac{l}{\left\lceil \delta^{-1} \right\rceil} \right\rceil \ge \frac{l}{\left\lceil \delta^{-1} \right\rceil} \ge \frac{l}{\left[ \delta^{-1} \right] + 1}.$$

The last step assumes that $\left[ x \right]$ stands for "the value $x$ rounded to the closest integer value".